# XML display node within node of same level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml in that amount an currency fields are like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
 -<GrpHdr>
  <MsgId>XMLV225022016Q2</MsgId>
  <Amount>10000</Amount>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
 </GrpHdr>
</Document>
```

but i want to display them like below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
 -<GrpHdr>
  <MsgId>XMLV225022016Q2</MsgId>
  <Amount Currency="USD">10000</Amount>
 </GrpHdr>
</Document>
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:t="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:Amount">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(../t:Currency)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="../t:Currency" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:Currency" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the output below

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId>XMLV225022016Q2</MsgId>
        <Amount Currency="USD">10000</Amount>
    </GrpHdr>
</Document>
```